# How can I track failed logins, and then block the IP address

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-identity

I have a Blazor Server app and it is using the ASP.NET Core Identity Library (which is MVC).

I want to implement code so that if a remote IP address has 50 failed logins over a 15 minute period, I then block that IP address for 4 hours from logging in.

Do I need to watch anything other than Login.cshtml.cs? I assume in there I can watch `OnPostAsync()` for failures and get the IP address on a failure. And on entry to it, return an error immediately if they are over the limit.

Is there any problem of tracking all this in a `Dictionary<IP_Address,Count>`?

I will be running on Azure using FrontDoor. Is there a way I can tell FrontDoor to ignore an IP address for a set period of time? I figure if so, that beats having the attempt come all the way to my code.

And am I missing anything on this?

**Not selecting an answer:** There are two different solutions below, by Ruikai Feng and Kurt Hamilton. Each has advantages and disadvantages. I don't want my selecting one to cause people to not read the other.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
//inject IMemoryCache
private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
public void OnPost()
{
    //when you failed to login
    var ipAddress = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
    var hasrecords=_cache.TryGetValue(ipAddress, out var records);
    if (!hasrecords)
    {
         var datetimeArr = new List<DateTime> { DateTime.Now };
        _cache.Set(ipAddress, datetimeArr, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(40));
    }
    else
    {
        var datetimeArr= records as List<DateTime>;
        datetimeArr?.Add(DateTime.Now );
        _cache.Set(ipAddress, datetimeArr, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(40));
    }

}
public override  async Task OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync(PageHandlerExecutingContext context,
                                         PageHandlerExecutionDelegate next)
{
    var ipAddress = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
    var hasrecords = _cache.TryGetValue(ipAddress, out var records);
    if (hasrecords)
    {
        var count = (records as List<DateTime>).Where(x => x.CompareTo(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-15)) > 0).ToArray().Count();
        if (count >= 40)
        {
            //block here
            context.Result = new ObjectResult("Forbid");
        }
        else
        {
            await next.Invoke();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        await next.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: Per my comment below - I am not accepting either answer as I think both are good solutions, each have trade-offs. I myself will use your answer but I can understand some people selecting @kurthamilton answer

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any problem of tracking all this in a
> Dictionary<IP_Address,Count>

There are numerous problems with this approach.

**1. Application lifecycle**

Using an in-memory dictionary (presumably a singleton) necessitates that your application does not recycle. You dictionary is disposed when then application recycles and a new dictionary is instantiated on the next request.

**2. Application instances**

Making an assumption about how your application is hosted is not ideal. A singleton dictionary lives on the current application instance. As soon as your application has multiple instances you cannot guarantee that a given IP will always send requests to a particular instance.

**3. Concurrency**

You are working in a multi-threaded environment - multiple requests could easily overlap, meaning that you need to manage concurrent dictionary reads and writes.  This would be easy to solve using a [ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=net-8.0).

### My approach

Essentially I am describing [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) properties, and to me it seems like a straightforward choice to record login attempts in your database.

Write (failed) login attempts to a table. At the minimum your schema would need to include timestamp and IP address. You could optionally include the login result if you want to include successful login attempts for any reason.

The login flow would look something like this:

```
Login 
  -> Read number of failed login attempts 
     from past 15 minutes for current IP address
     -> Over failure threshold? 
        -> Return 403 / Appropriate error message
  -> Login Success?
     -> [Log to database]
     -> Return Redirect to next page
  -> Login Failed?
     -> Log to database
     -> Return Redirect to login page
```

**Considerations**

Client IP addresses are not necessarily fixed, and can be spoofed. This is a decent first layer of defence to rate-limit brute force attacks.

Your log table is going to grow over time. Optimise the table indexes for reads rather than writes - you do not want to penalise happy cases.

You could store blocked IP addresses in a separate table with a `BlockedUntil` timestamp. This would enable you to:

- Simplify your database reads at the point of login (reducing the table growth problem)
- Use enhanced timeout logic (e.g. 15 minute timeout for first strike, 30 minutes for second strike, etc)

The enhanced login flow would look something like this:

```
Login 
  -> Read number of records for current IP address 
     from block list where BlockedUntil is after 
     current time
     -> Count greater than zero? 
        -> Return 403 / Appropriate error message
  -> Login Success?
     -> [Log to database]
     -> Return Redirect to next page
  -> Login Failed?
     -> Log to database
     -> Over threshold?
        -> Add record to block list with 
           appropriate BlockedUntil timestamp
        -> Return 403 / Appropriate error message
     -> Return Redirect to login page
```

Comment: Doesn't hitting the DB mean opening the login page is a bit slower? And as you said, the database starts to fill up. I'm setting Affinity??? in Azure App Service so that a given remote IP will usually be fed to the same server. ???

Comment: As with everything in programming, there is a tradeoff. If you are worried about database queries slowing your application then why use a database at all? In my opinion it is by far better to use a very quick (few ms) database call versus having untrusted data stored with my application.

Comment: Storing persistent data in the application is littered with problems - which is what the original question asked about, and I highlighted 3 problems (smarter people than me could highlight more). Using the solution you marked as the answer is a fundamentally bad solution, but whatever ‍♂️

Comment: " I'm setting Affinity??? in Azure App Service so that a given remote IP will usually be fed to the same server". Probably. Possibly. If that's good enough for you, then fair enough. It wouldn't be good enough for me. Aren't you interested in seeing how many failed login attempts you're getting? Tracking the history of failed login attempts would be impossible with the accepted solution.

Comment: You raise some very good points. I'm going to accept neither as I think both answers provide a good solution, each with advantages & disadvantages. As to tracking the failed logins, I don't see any real value in that. There will be a ton of attempts and there's no gain from knowing that N attempts came from 1.2.3.4.

Comment: Fair enough! For all my talk of doing the "right" thing, it's easy to forget that you really only need a solution that's good enough for your situation. The needs of a small personal project are different from the needs of an enterprise large scale app. Your motivation for doing this might be different from what I was imagining, leading to false assumptions on my part. Either way, happy Blazoring!

Comment: About 15 years ago we got a directive to figure out who was trying to break into our website. So we wired it up to track where attempts were coming from and what they tried. And then we took that information and started finding what was at the other end. And... we could never act on it. Over the course of two days we had over 1,000 remote IP addresses hitting us with thousands of requests. And not a single one we dived into was something on which we could take any action. I've heard the same from many others - it's rarely worth figuring out who is hitting you, even if you can.